# PHP - Call a method from the class where i instantiated my object

Tags: php, oop

I have 2 classes declared like in the example below.

```
class A{
   protected $process;

   public function __construct() {
      ......
      $this->process=new B();

   }

   public function do_something(){
     ....
   }

}

class B{
 // content not important
 // I need to call do_something from class A     

}
```

My question is, how can I call from class B the method `do_something()` from class A?  Is it possible?

Comment: Either make `B` and extension of `A`, or create a new object of `A` inside `B` and call that method.

Comment: We don't really know enough about the overall architecture do give a recommendation. Do you want to call the method of the instance of `A` which this instance of `B` is contained in? In this case, you could pass the instance of `A` to the constructor of `B` and store it in a member variable, to call its method later.

Comment: `$this->process = new B($this);`, store it in B's constructor, call what you need.

Comment: Have you tried anything to get that working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example it is impossible for instance of `B` to know that it is instantiated and stored by an instance of class `A`. You need to create that connection explicitly in some way.

I didn't think this would even work, but apparently you can pass instance of `A` to `B` before `A` is even done with its constructor:

```php
class A {
    protected $process;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->process = new B( $this );

    }

    public function do_something() {
        var_dump( 'do_something' );
    }

    public function test() {
        $this->process->test();
    }
}

class B {

    public function __construct( A $a ) {
        $this->a = $a;
    }

    public function test() {
        $this->a->do_something();
    }
}

$a = new A();

$a->test(); // do_something
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give an advice on what the best approach for your particular case would be, as we don't know what either `A` or `B` does.

There's a few ways to achieve this. One way would be to make B and extension of A - thereby allowing all methods of the class `A` to be callable on the object `B`. Another way is to create a new object of A inside B and call that method. Or you can pass

Here's an example where B is extended from A. By doing this, all properties and methods of `A` can be called on `B`, unless overwritten in `B`.

```
class A {
    public function doSomething(){
        echo "doSomething() called in A";
    }

}
class B extends A {
    public function someMethod() {
        $this->doSomething();
    }
}

$b = new B();
$b->someMethod();
```

The above would output `doSomething() called in A`.

Or, you can create an object `A` and call that method inside `B`.

```
class B {
    public function someMethod() {
        $a = new A();
        $a->do_something();
    }
}
$b = new B();
$b->someMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading all the answers and doing some research i think that the best method for me was the use of Traits

"Traits are a mechanism for code reuse in single inheritance languages such as PHP. A Trait is intended to reduce some limitations of single inheritance by enabling a developer to reuse sets of methods freely in several independent classes living in different class hierarchies."

So i  declared a Trait with the method do_something and call that method from Both class A and Class B

Thanks